# Flutter, start with deep link

Tags: flutter, web, startup

So I want to add deep links to an existing app. If I enter a deep link with parameters in the web browser after starting the app, it works.
There are a lot of widgets, so I can't and don't want to create a list of possible routes beforehand. In addition, it should also be possible to transfer parameters.
As I said, everything works as desired when the app is running. Unfortunately, I can't get it to run the same functionality as onGenerateRoute when it starts.
I've already tried with routes, onGenerateInitialRoutes,.. Unfortunately without success.

here is the code for the main view. However, the MainView should only be displayed if no parameter is passed.

```
return AppBuilder(builder: (context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    title: 'testDummy',
    supportedLocales: SUPPORTED_LOCALES.keys,
    locale: model.appLocal,
    localizationsDelegates: const [
      AppLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    ],
    theme: buildTheme(),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: MainView(),
    navigatorKey: NavigationService.instance.navigationKey,        
    onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
      return createRoute(context, settings);
    }
  );
});
```

The question is where do I have to call something so that the functionality I want is achieved.
in onGenerateInitialRoutes the passed parameters are already provided. But I didn't get any further. I then had error messages with double keys. Also, I'm not sure what to put in the list. First the MainView and then next the route to the widget to be called. I've tried, but to no avail.
Can someone please give me a tip.